# HTML Template in Gmail Renders Incorrect

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

Im sending a mail from a template using [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/). But renders incorrectly on Gmail.

Im not using any style tags or any complex css.

ps: im not sure how much text i should add to be accpeted.

Here is the html template

**Template:**

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Communication</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#fff" style="background-color:#fff;">
                <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: solid 1px #000;margin-top:60px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#001529" style="background-color:#001529; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:10px;">
                            <div style="font-size:36px; color:#fff;">
                                <b>FORGOT YOUR PASSWORD?</b>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#fff" style="background-color:#fff;">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="color:#525252; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:10px;">
                                        <div style="font-size:16px;">
                                            Dear {0},
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="font-size:16px;">
                                            <p>A request has been received to reset your password for your -- account. Please click the button below to reset your password.</p>
                                            <center>
                                                <button type="button" title="Confirm Account Registration" style="background: #00415a;border:1px solid #00415a;">
                                                    <a href="{1}" style="font-size:22px; padding: 6px 12px; color: #f2faff;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block">
                                                        Reset Password Now
                                                    </a>
                                                </button>

                                            </center>
                                            <p style="font-size:16px;">If you did not make this request please igonore this email.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="padding:15px; background-color:#00415a; font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px; color:#f2faff;">
                                        <p>Regards<br/>
                                        -- © {2}</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it renders in Gmail:

**Gmail:**

[image: Gmail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minifying the template seemed to fix the issue.

Bear in mind this is not a Gmail issue rather a Mailgun issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give a line-height to both title and button text, and should fix it.

Also i recommend against using margin-top or bottom in emails/tables but always go with padding instead. For some reason is more compatible. If you need some space above for instance, create a empty div above the element and give it a height.

Comment: Thanks, the main problem is that there extra white space. Whn inspecting the code on gmail it seems that there are extra 'tr' and 'br' elements not found in source